# Using epoll to monitor inotify events

Tags: go, epoll, inotify

I want to use inotify to watch some file changes, and use epoll to monitor if any inotify event occurs. However, I was having some trouble receiving inotify events. Say, how do I know if I got every events that occured.

If inotify fd sets to NON_BLOCK mode, EAGAIN would get returned when `read()` indicating that there's nothing else left to read, which is nice. But If inotify fd sets to BLOCKING mode, `read()` would block infinitely.

> For example, if you
> call read(2) by asking to read a certain amount of data and
> read(2) returns a lower number of bytes, you can be sure of
> having exhausted the read I/O space for the file descriptor.
>
> Ref: [epoll(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)

According to [epoll(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), I can assure a thorough read if `read()` returns a lower number of bytes. But how should I deal with `read()` returning the same number of bytes ?

Here's the code I've tried.

```golang
func main() {
    fd, _ := unix.InotifyInit()
    epollfd, _ := unix.EpollCreate(1)
    unix.EpollCtl(epollfd, unix.EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &unix.EpollEvent{
        Fd:     int32(fd),
        Events: unix.EPOLLIN,
    })
    unix.InotifyAddWatch(fd, os.Args[1], unix.IN_ALL_EVENTS)
    epollevents := make([]unix.EpollEvent, 8)
    for {
        // epoll wait
        var nepoll int
        if nepoll, err = unix.EpollWait(epollfd, epollevents, -1); err == nil {
            // nothing happens
        } else if errors.Is(err, unix.EINTR) {
            continue // ignore interrupt
        } else {
            log.Fatal(err.Error())
        }
        // process inotify events
        for i := 0; i < nepoll; i += 1 {
            var nr int
            // buff for receiving
            // eventBuf for processing
            // two buff to prevent a large amount of data
            eventBuff := make([]byte, (unix.SizeofInotifyEvent+unix.PathMax)*2)
            buff := make([]byte, unix.SizeofInotifyEvent+unix.PathMax)
            offset, nr, lastUnread := 0, 0, 0
            for {
                // read loop in case of a large amount of data
                if nr, err = unix.Read(int(epollevents[i].Fd), buff); err == nil {
                    // nothing happens
                } else if errors.Is(err, unix.EAGAIN) {
                    println("exhaust")
                    break
                } else {
                    log.Fatal(err.Error())
                }
                copy(eventBuff[lastUnread:lastUnread+nr], buff[:nr])
                lastUnread += nr
                for offset < lastUnread &&
                    (nr < len(buff) || lastUnread-offset >= unix.PathMax+unix.SizeofInotifyEvent) {
                    event := (*unix.InotifyEvent)(unsafe.Pointer(&eventBuff[offset]))
                    switch event.Mask {
                    case unix.IN_ACCESS:
                        // ...
                    case unix.IN_OPEN:
                        // ...
                    case unix.IN_CLOSE_WRITE:
                        // ...
                    case unix.IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE:
                        // ...
                    }
                    offset += unix.SizeofInotifyEvent + int(event.Len)
                }
                copy(eventBuff[offset:lastUnread], eventBuff[:lastUnread-offset])
                lastUnread -= offset
                offset = 0
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("Over") // NEVER got print out in BLOCKING mode
    }
}
```